# Same and Different Random Numbers generation

Tags: c++, random

I am creating this game which involves generating random numbers. I have to add an option (at the end of the game) to restart the same game or create a new game. How can I generate same and different random numbers?

Answer (score 4):

Save the seed you use in `srand()` to generate identical random numbers, initialize the seed based on `time()` to generate new sequences every time.

Answer (score 2):

```
/* srand example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

int main ()
{
    printf ("First number: %d\n", rand()%100);
    srand (time(NULL));
    printf ("Random number: %d\n", rand()%100);
    srand (1);
    printf ("Again the first number: %d\n", rand()%100);

    return 0;
}
```

The above code is from the srand example found here: [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/)

It shows both how you can use time() and srand() to get a random number, and how you can retrieve already generated numbers again.